# How to perform operations on pointers to a struct?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have a C program that has multiple functions that do different computing on rectangles. I have defined structs in order to map the rectangles and the points of the rectangle. I'm stuck on a function (moveR) that takes in a rectangle pointer and two int values as parameters and then moves the rectangle based on those parameters.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]The problem I am running into is that the function does not update the new position. For example, in my call of 'moveR()' it should move the x value of the upper left corner of the rectangle to 18, but it keeps returning 15. Any help would be appreciated!

````
#include <stdio.h>

    struct point{
        int x, y;
    } point1, point2, answer, point1b, point2b;
    
    struct rectangle{
        struct point upperLeft, lowerRight;
    } R1;
    
    struct point centerR (struct rectangle R1){
        int centerx= (R1.lowerRight.x-R1.upperLeft.x)/2;
        int centery= (R1.lowerRight.y-R1.upperLeft.y)/2;
        struct point pointR;
        pointR.x= centerx;
        pointR.y= centery;
        return pointR;
    } 
    
    struct rectangle moveR(struct rectangle *R1, int x, int y){
        R1->upperLeft.x+x;
        R1->lowerRight.x+x;
        R1->upperLeft.y+y;
        R1->lowerRight.y+y;
        
        return *R1;
    }
    
    struct rectangle *R2;
    
    
int main()
{
    point1.x= 6;
    point1.y= 6;
    point2.x= 10;
    point2.y= 12;
    
    R1.upperLeft= point1;
    R1.lowerRight= point2;
    
    answer = centerR(R1);
    
    printf("The center of R1 is:\n");
    printf("The x value of the center is %d \n", answer.x);
    printf("The y value of the center is %d \n", answer.y);
    
    R2=  &R1;
    point1b.x=15;
    point1b.y=15;
    point2b.x=25;
    point2b.y=25;
    R2->upperLeft = point1b;
    R2->lowerRight= point2b;
    
    moveR(R2,3,4);
    
    printf("The position of R2 is:\n");
    printf("The x value of the upper left is %d \n", R1.upperLeft.x);
    
    return 0;
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2pO5.png
````

Comment: Where does the result of `R1->upperLeft.x+x;` go?

Comment: In my mind, it's supposed to update the value of R2 when I call it.

Comment: I think there should be R1->upperLeft.x += x; or R1->upperLeft.x = R1->upperLeft.x + x;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the math here:

```
R1->upperLeft.x+x;
R1->lowerRight.x+x;
R1->upperLeft.y+y;
R1->lowerRight.y+y;
```

So where do you save the result? Do you intended to save updated results in R1 like following?

```
R1->upperLeft.x += x;
R1->lowerRight.x += x;
R1->upperLeft.y += y;
R1->lowerRight.y += y;
```